# Ember - run JS on DOM load

Tags: ember.js

I'm building a simple Ember CLI based chat app. I have a list of messages which are asynchronously loaded, and I want to scroll to the bottom when they are all loaded using some simple JS like this:

```
Ember.$('.conversation').scrollTop( Ember.$('.conversation')[0].scrollHeight );
```

Where should I put this code such that it runs after all the message objects are loaded and rendered?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

More details of the code - I'm using a conversation route/controller/template to load a single conversation object. The conversation model hasMany messages with {async: true} in the model description. The route looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('conversation', params.conversation_id);
  }
});
```

And the template looks something like:

```
<div class="conversation">
    {{#each message in messages}}
        <div class="message">{{message.body}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

For a conversation with lots of messages I want to scroll to the bottom of the .conversation div when all the messages are loaded. I am not sure where to put the javascript code for this.

Comment: check out initializers http://ember.zone/ember-application-initializers/

Comment: @AdamP can you share how and where are you loading this aynch data? Is it in controller? Is same code used every-time to load data ?

Comment: More details in update above - thanks for your help.

Comment: Also thanks @iwayneo - initializers look like a great solution for app-wide functions, but I only want to run this javascript on the conversation template, not on every page.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do this:

```
return this.store.find('conversation', params.conversation_id).then(function(results){
     //whatever your code is here:
     Ember.$('.conversation').scrollTop( Ember.$('.conversation')[0].scrollHeight );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making conversation into a component (everything in Ember is moving towards becoming a component these days ;)). Inside the component, you can **observe** for the `body` property of the `message` and execute the code using `Ember.run.scheduleOnce`. You can read up more on the run loop in general [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/).

Your component would like as follows:

```
App.ZConversationComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['conversation'],
  watchMessages: function(){
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.scrollToMessage);    
  }.observes('conversation.messages.@each.body'),

  scrollToMessage: function(){
    console.log('Start scrolling');
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $('.conversation').offset().top}, 1000);   
  }
});
```

And your templates would like as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='index'>
  <div class='tall'>SOME CONTENT ON PAGE</div>
  <div class='tall'>MORE CONTENT ON PAGE</div>

  {{ z-conversation conversation=model}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/z-conversation">

  {{#each message in conversation.messages}}
    <div class="message">{{message.body}}</div>
  {{/each}}

</script>
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/selini/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

(I used a `FixtureAdapter`, but threw in a `latency` to make it more realistic)